# How can a dhcp client in linux can send a custom option?

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp

I need a DHCP client to send a string to the server as part of the DHCP request. I have tried setting DHCP options in the client, but they are not being sent during the initial DHCP handshake.

The dhcp-options manpage shows how new options can be defined. But these seem to be sent only from the DHCP server to the DHCP client. How can I send options from the DHCP client to the server instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using dhclient then you need to edit the dhclient.conf file; on my system it's in /etc/dhcp. You can get a list of parameters understood by dhclient in dhclient.conf's man page.